# How to replace strings and get what I need in this case?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to replace a string with two sets of patterns. For example,

```
var pattern1 = '12345abcde/';  -> this is dynamic.
var myString = '12345abcde/hd123/godaddy_item'
```

my end goal is to get the value between two slashes which is `hd123`

I have

```
var stringIneed = myString.replace(pattern1, '').replace('godaddy_item','');
```

The above codes work but I think there is more elegant solution. Can anyone help me out on this? Thanks a lot!

**UPDATE**: 
   To be more clear, the pattern is per environement string. For example,
`pattern1` could be something like:

```
https://myproject-development/item on development environment.
```

and

```
https://myproject/item on Production
```

`myString` could usually be like

```
https://myproject/item/hd123/godaddy_item
```

or

```
https://myproject-development/item/hd123/godaddy_item
```

and I need to get '`hd123`' in my case.

Comment: what about myString.split("/")[1]

Comment: Will it always be - as is the case in your two examples - the penultimate portion of the string that you want?

Comment: Then isn't it always something like this?-
`myString.split('/').slice(-2)[0]`

Comment: In which case take a look at my updated answer, which should do as you require.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd strongly suggest not using regular expressions for this, especially when simple `String` and `Array` methods will easily suffice and be far more understandable, such as:

```js
// your question shows you can anticipate the sections you
// don't require, so put both/all of those portions into an
// array:
var unwanted = ['12345abcde', 'godaddy_item'],

  // the string you wish to find the segment from:
  myString = '12345abcde/hd123/godaddy_item',

  // splitting the String into an array by splitting on the '/'
  // characters, filtering that array using an arrow function
  // in which the section is the current array-element of the
  // array over which we're iterating; and here we keep those
  // sections which are not found in the unwanted Array (the index
  // an element not found in an Array is returned as -1):
  desired = myString.split('/').filter(section => unwanted.indexOf(section) === -1);

console.log(desired); // ["hd123"]
```

Avoiding Arrow functions, for browsers not supporting ES6 (and having removed the code comments):

```js
var unwanted = ['12345abcde', 'godaddy_item'],
  myString = '12345abcde/hd123/godaddy_item',
  desired = myString.split('/').filter(function (section) {
   return unwanted.indexOf(section) === -1;
  });

console.log(desired); // ["hd123"]
```

Or:

```js
// the string to start with and filter:
var myString = '12345abcde/hd123/godaddy_item',

  // splitting the string by the '/' characters and keeping those whose
  // index is greater than 0 (so 'not the first') and also less than the
  // length of the array-1 (since JS arrays are zero-indexed while length
  // is 1-based):
  wanted = myString.split('/').filter((section, index, array) => index > 0 && index < array.length - 1);

console.log(wanted); // ["hd123"]
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/4w1gjgqz/1/)

If, however, the requisite string to be found is always the penultimate portion of the supplied string, then we can use `Array.prototype.filter()` to return only that portion:

```js
var myString = '12345abcde/hd123/godaddy_item',
  wanted = myString.split('/').filter((section, index, array) => index === array.length - 2);

console.log(wanted); // ["hd123"]
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/4w1gjgqz/2/).

References:

- [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).
- [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
- [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

Comment: As he already pointed out- the unwanted array can be a dynamic list of `Strings`. How can he populate that beforehand?

Comment: In the same way he currently uses/assigns the variable string. But without more information in the original question I'm unable to specify precisely *how* he could/should do so (or if there's a better way).

Comment: @Md.AbdulMunim yes I can't really populate that into the array. +1 tho

Comment: In that case, the regex one would be more dynamic and proper solution for the problem- as it will be able to get all the matches in a string which has a preceding and ending */*. @FlyingCat

Comment: Can you update your question to show how exactly you're retrieving/assigning the Strings you don't want? Because your code example shows that you are able to dynamically store them. Presumably your code is wrapped in a function of some sort, can you show that in full?

Comment: @FlyingCat another way around could be a little modification of what David did. Like below: 
`myString.split('/').filter(function (section, index, array) {
   return index > 0 && index < array.length - 1;
  });`

Comment: Thanks guys, please see my updated question. slightly different than my original question.

Comment: the question was to make it simple..i don't think it made it any simpler

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
.*\/([^\/]+)\/.*$
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jN5zG6/4)**

*JS Demo*

```js
var re = /.*\/([^\/]+)\/.*$/g;
var str = '12345abcde/hd123/godaddy_item';

while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    document.writeln("<pre>" + m[1] + "</br>" + "</pre>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do something like this:
`myString.split('/').slice(-2)[0]`

This will return the item directly, in simple most way.

```js
var myString = 'https://myproject/item/hd123/godaddy_item';
console.log(myString.split('/').slice(-2)[0]); // hd123
myString = 'https://myproject-development/item/hd123/godaddy_item';
console.log(myString.split('/').slice(-2)[0]); // hd123
```

Answer (score 0):

To say that David's answer will "easily suffice and be far more understandable" is a matter of opinion - this regex option (which includes building up the expression from variables) really couldn't be much simpler:

```
var pathPrefix = '12345abcde/'; //dynamic
var pathToTest = '12345abcde/hd123/godaddy_item';
var pattern = new RegExp(pathPrefix + '(.*?)\/')
var match = pattern.exec(pathToTest);
var result = (match != null && match[1] != null ? '[' + match[1] + ']' : 'no match was found.'); //[hd123]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `match()` as shown below:

```js
var re = /\/(.*)\//;
var str = '12345abcde/hd123/godaddy_item';
var result = str.match(re);
alert(result[1]);
```